# Can not properly hide images in outlook 2013 HTML Emails

Tags: html, outlook, gmail, html-email

I'm having problem hiding images properly in outlook 2013, even though they are hidden they add a line of spacing where they have been hidden making the email look stretched. This is the code I have on the image that I want to hide from the desktop version.

```
<tr style="display: none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; height: 0; padding: 0; mso-hide: all;">
 <td width="20" style="display: none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; height: 0; padding: 0; mso-hide: all;" class="spacer-width">
  <img class="spacer-width" src="spacer.gif" height="0" width="0" style="display: none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; height: 0; padding: 0; mso-hide: all;" alt="" />
 </td>
 <td width="560" style="display: none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; height: 0; padding: 0; mso-hide: all;" class="secondary-fullwidth">
  <img src="btn-8.gif" height="0" width="0" style="display: none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; height: 0; padding: 0; mso-hide: all;" class="btn-two" alt="Request A Test Drive" />
 </td>
 <td width="20" style="display: none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; height: 0; padding: 0; mso-hide: all;" class="spacer-width">
  <img class="spacer-width" src="spacer.gif" height="0" width="0" style="display: none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; height: 0; padding: 0; mso-hide: all;" alt="" />
 </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding visibility:hidden; to the css. It has support in Outlook and I remember somewhere that the "new" Internet Explorer (maybe I was working with 8 at the time) needed both to properly hide something.

Comment: I was not able to get this to hide img in outlook, either inline or page level css. style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;"

Answer (score 1):

I use the following fix to hide the content from Outlook 2007 and up:

```
    <!--[if !gte mso 9]><!---->
    <tr style="display: none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; height: 0; padding: 0; mso-hide: all;">
 <td width="20" style="display: none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; height: 0; padding: 0; mso-hide: all;" class="spacer-width">
  <img class="spacer-width" src="spacer.gif" height="0" width="0" style="display: none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; height: 0; padding: 0; mso-hide: all;" alt="" />
 </td>
 <td width="560" style="display: none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; height: 0; padding: 0; mso-hide: all;" class="secondary-fullwidth">
  <img src="btn-8.gif" height="0" width="0" style="display: none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; height: 0; padding: 0; mso-hide: all;" class="btn-two" alt="Request A Test Drive" />
 </td>
 <td width="20" style="display: none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; height: 0; padding: 0; mso-hide: all;" class="spacer-width">
  <img class="spacer-width" src="spacer.gif" height="0" width="0" style="display: none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; height: 0; padding: 0; mso-hide: all;" alt="" />
 </td>
</tr>
<!--<![endif]-->
```