# How to hide elements on Outlook email client

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

There is an element that I want to hide on desktop but then display on mobile. Using the following styles are just hit and miss for me:

```
mso-hide: all;
display: none;
width: 0;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
```

Sometimes this works, sometimes it just doesn't. I've noticed that it really just depends on how nested the element is. If it is nested quite a bit, good luck, that boy ain't hiding.

Is there any way to reliable hide content on outlook email clients?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not properly hide images in outlook 2013 HTML Emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274278/can-not-properly-hide-images-in-outlook-2013-html-emails)

Comment: This also will do the trick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70840411/hide-content-in-outlook-with-external-css

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional HTML comments:

```
<!--[if !mso]>-->
<div>This won’t show in Outlook</div>
<!--<![endif]-->
```